# Term of art for "agent-slotting" delusion?

Tags: cognitive-modeling, schizophrenia

Some years ago I read about the computational modeling of schizophrenia.  (It was probably a summary in a layperson's science publication like *Science News*.)

As I recall, altering a single variable relating to memory caused a particular type of delusion to arise in the AI patient where, in the recalling of a narrative, characters in the action were substituted with each other, or with the speaker.  In the article, this was referred to as an "agent-slotting error".

Web searches for "agent-slotting error" only seem to turn up references to the modeling research, so I would like to know:

- Is this type of error or delusion something that's actually associated with schizophrenia, or is it just considered a model for understanding aspects of delusions in schizophrenia?
- If it is something that actually occurs in schizophrenia, what is a term of art for it used generally in psychology rather than specifically in computational models of cognition?

---

Some clarifying examples from the papers:

From [Comprehensive review: Computational modelling of schizophrenia
Vincent Valtona](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/pseries/Peg_files/valton2017.pdf):

> The hyperlearning model could account for derailments from the original
> story through a confusion between the characters of different stories
> (‘agent-slotting errors’) leading to delusion-like ideas (Grasemann et al.,
> 2009; Hoffman et al., 2011).

[Grasemann et al.](https://escholarship.org/content/qt31d5h9qq/qt31d5h9qq.pdf) actually calls it “agency shifts”:

> Applied to the story and sentence generator networks, hyperlearning robustly produced stable patterns of “agency shifts” where characters migrated between stories and produced meaningful new narratives.

Comment: Could you be referring to [source-monitoring error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-monitoring_error#Schizophrenia)?

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg I don't think it's the same.  I'll update the question to include examples from one of the papers.